# last item in the cart

Tags: java, microservices, shopping-cart

I am learning microservices and trying to design an e-commerce website. I can't figure out how big shopping sites take care of the last item in the cart problem.

For example, I selected an item from Amazon which had just a single item available in stock. I logged in from two different accounts and placed the item in cart. I even reached the payment page from both the account and the site didn't restrict me anywhere saying that the item is not available. I am not sure after the payment page when payment from both the account is in progress, how Amazon handles it.

Few solutions which come to my mind are like:

1. Accept payment from both the accounts and later cancel transaction for one of them which paid later than the first. This will not be a good practice though as it will result in bas customer experience.
2. Keep few items in reserve and use them in case of overbooking.
3. I forget what Amazon is doing and implement quantity checks in Order service from Item service via REST calls, at every stage of the order. But these checks sometimes can fail when a lot of people are ordering the same item. for e.g. in flash sales

Please share if you guys have worked on similar problem and solved it even with few limitations. If I need to put any in more details, let me know.

Comment: Always consider upvoting an answer if it leads you to a solution. consider accepting if it fully served your purpose. This encourages developers to answer more thereby growing the community which ultimately benefits us only.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot answer how Amaozon does it, nor I think anyone could on a public forum I can tell you how I think this could be managed.
So you have to take lock on your inventory if you want to make sure you precisely map inventory to an order. If you intend to do that, question will be where you take lock. When an item gets added to the cart, when user goes for payment or when payment is done. But the problem with lock is that it will make you system slow.
So that is something you should avoid.

Rest all the options you have already covered in your question and it boils down to tradeoffs.

First point, user experience will suffer and you also need to incur the cost of the transaction.

Second option ask you to be ready to undersell or oversell.
When you keep reserves, you are basically saying that I will be underselling. This can also backfire because say you decide to reserve 5 items but you get 20 concurrent request foir checkout and payment, you will be back to the square one. But it can help in most scenarios, given you are willing to take a hit.

Doing inventory check at checkout can help you get better resolution on inventory but it will not help when you literally have last item in inventory and 10 people doing a checkout on it. Read calls even for two such request coincides you will give them inventory and back to square one.

So what I do in such scenarios, is
1. My inventory goes not as number but enum i.e critical, low, med, high, very high
Depending on some analytics we configure inventory check. For high and very high we will not do any check and book the item. for critical and we take the lock. (not exactly a db lock but we reserve the inventory for them), for low and medium we check the inventory and proceed if we have enough. All these values are configurable and help us mitigate the scenarios we have.

Another thing that we are trying is to distribute inventory to inventory brokers and assign inventory broker to some set of services to see this inventory. Even if we reserve the inventory on one broker others can continue selling freely. And there brokers regularly update the inventory master about the status of inventory. Its like Inventory master has 50 items, it distributes 5 each to all ten. After 10 mins they come back and if they need more inventory they ask for it, if they have left over (in case of failure) they drop back inventory to the master for it to be assigned to others.

The above approach will not help you resolve the issue precisely but it gives you certain degree of freedom as to how you can manage the inventory.

Comment: Thanks. I like your thoughts. I think big shopping sites must have implemented a mixed solution using all of these approaches.

Comment: I'd like to stress a little bit on what I believe is the important take away of the @anunay answer: it's not (yet) a technical problem that deserves a technical solution. The first question should be answered by the business: what should we do, in our specific domain when (not if) this scenario will happen? Different business apply different policies, once you have the answer you can start thinking about technical concern.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing:

1. On the payment page, you should re-check if the product is still available. This can be a simple HTTP GET.
2. If the GET call is slow for you, consider caching recent product added by user to some in-memory databases (eg. REDIS). Now if first users successfully processes the payment, decrease counter for that product-id in redis. And before proceeding payment for second user, check the counter of that product-id in redis.

(BONUS: Redis offers atomic operations, so you can successfully handle the race condition in ordering the product as well.)

Comment: Question is when will you fire the decrement request? The user may abort the order any time during the flow and that may result in premature order rejection for other users.